# Cannot start the debugger in Rubymine. Rails server launcher wasn't found in project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, rubymine-7

I was trying to debug a rails application(4.03) using rubymine IDE version 7.0.2, but when I configure my application like this
[image]

The IDE complained that Rails Server launcher wasn't found in the project.

Please tell me what can I do fix the issue, and could you please recommend other ways of debugging a rails application.

Please note that this bug is easily replicated using Ruby Mine by following these steps.

1. Create a new rails projects with Ruby Mine, for example DebuggingRails. Which will generate default folders and files. At this point one can debug the application normally.
2. Create a new folder let's say Server.
3. Copy all the generated files above to the Server folder, so the project structure will be
   DebuggingRails\Server.
4. Create a debugging configuration , which points to the DebuggingRails\Server.
5. Try to debug the application using the IDE.
6. The message "Rails server launcher wasn't found in project" appears

Thanks.

Comment: try to use the `byebug gem` https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug Required: MRI 2.0.0 or higher. For debugging ruby 1.9.3 or older, use debugger.

Comment: Thanks, that is probably the option I would go if there is no other options.

Answer (score 13):

Close your project, remove the `.idea` folder, and open it back up again.

Comment: Actually, I had to use byebug to debug on console

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because i chose the wrong folder, you must choose the root folder in the rails project. For example i had this structure

```
-MyProject
---RoR
-----app
-----bin
-----condig
-----etc
```

Then I chose the folder call

> MyProject

It was wrong.

The correct is choose the folder

> RoR

Answer (score 1):

`bundle binstubs railties`

or

`rake rails:update:bin`

This will generate the `bin/rails` file which RubyMine is looking for in your project.