# Rubymine RoR project is empty/rails server wasn't found in project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, rubygems, rubymine

When I create a Rails project in Rubymine it stops straight away, saying "Rails server wasn't found in project".

I installed rails (it turns up in the SDK settings too) and I tried [deleting .idea and restarting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141740/rubymine-rails-server-launcher-wasnt-found-in-the-project).

I have done this before on another machine, but not sure what else to debug at this point - any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

I think its most probably that you are not opening the correct folder. For me it solved when i opened the sub folder which contains the rails project instead of parent folder.