# Getting "jruby: no Ruby script found in input (LoadError)" while running rails application in Rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, rubymine

Apologies if it's a duplicate question. Asking this as I haven't got any solution yet. Trying to run rails application in Rubymine. I have setup the configuration in Rubymine so that on click on run button, rails server starts. Through command line, `rails s` works.

Getting this below error when I click on Run button to start rails server in development mode.

```
/opt/jruby/bin/jruby -x /opt/jruby/bin/bundle exec /opt/jruby/bin/jruby /Users/satyapramod/Documents/rails_projects/test-app/script/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development
jruby: no Ruby script found in input (LoadError)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This project is using jruby. Here are the jruby and rails versions.
jruby: 9.1.17.0
rails: 2.3.0
Using mac OS monterey 12.3

Please suggest me where I am going wrong. Let me know if anything is required from my end.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I once solved this problem by disabling Bundler Auto-detection.
Attaching screenshot for reference.
[image]